# TCP/IP connection timed out

Tags: tcp

I wrote a java program of TCP/IP Client which is supposed to read data from TCPIP server device.

Problem is when I give the IP and Port of the Device, java gives error of "Connection Time out". Obviously this is problem of not connecting to that Device.

I want to know if there is way to know where the problem is?  Whether that TCPIP server device is not reachable (if no, then how to check it )

whether Its the router / network issue that TCPIP Client and Server has to be on same network or use same router to communicate. OR Just IP:Port is enough.

How on my computer may I know that TCPIP server device is turned on and streaming??

---

P.S. That TCPIP Server device can also be connected with blutooth connection. can i read streaming through blutooth in Java?? if yes what/How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there is way to know where the problem is? Whether
>   that TCPIP server device is not reachable (if no, then how to check it
>   )

Use telnet from the client - it will try to connect to the remote server at the port that you specify. For example `telnet google.com 80` attempts to reach google.com on port 80. You could also use an IP address in place of "google.com". If you are on a windows box, you might have to enable telnet first.

You can also use netstat on the server. It should say the ports that are currently open and the state that they are in. For example, your Java server program should be listening on the port, so the state should say LISTEN.